# minikube start error virtualbox 6.1 ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, minikube

I am trying to run this command but get error in making virtualbox.

```
minikube start --driver=virtualbox
```

```
asad@asadzoot:~$ minikube start --driver=virtualbox
  minikube v1.11.0 on Ubuntu 20.04
✨  Using the virtualbox driver based on user configuration
  Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
  Creating virtualbox VM (CPUs=2, Memory=2200MB, Disk=20000MB) ...
  StartHost failed, but will try again: creating host: create: precreate: We support Virtualbox starting with version 5. Your VirtualBox install is "WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.\n\t Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate\n\t headers, most likely linux-headers-generic.\n\n\t You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.\n6.1.6_Ubuntur137129". Please upgrade at https://www.virtualbox.org
  Creating virtualbox VM (CPUs=2, Memory=2200MB, Disk=20000MB) ...
  Failed to start virtualbox VM. "minikube start" may fix it: creating host: create: precreate: We support Virtualbox starting with version 5. Your VirtualBox install is "WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.\n\t Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate\n\t headers, most likely linux-headers-generic.\n\n\t You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.\n6.1.6_Ubuntur137129". Please upgrade at https://www.virtualbox.org

❌  [VBOX_DEVICE_MISSING] error provisioning host Failed to start host: creating host: create: precreate: We support Virtualbox starting with version 5. Your VirtualBox install is "WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.\n\t Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate\n\t headers, most likely linux-headers-generic.\n\n\t You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.\n6.1.6_Ubuntur137129". Please upgrade at https://www.virtualbox.org
  Suggestion: Reinstall VirtualBox and reboot. Alternatively, try the kvm2 driver: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/reference/drivers/kvm2/
⁉️   Related issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/3974
```

Please see the screenshots below:

[screenshot-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usSrL.jpg)

[screenshot-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0WdC.jpg)

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu using WSL?

Comment: yes! using ubuntu but not use WSL. I run Kubernetes directly in ubuntu Linux

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with virtual box 6.x.

I chooses the option:  Alternatively, try the kvm2 driver: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/reference/drivers/kvm2/
⁉️   Related issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/3974

My operating system: Ubuntu 20.04

Step 1: install debian

https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/kvm2/

https://wiki.debian.org/KVM#Installation

give command: **minikube start --driver=kvm2**

Now if you end up with error(then go to step2):

**Exiting due to PROVIDER_KVM2_ERROR: /usr/bin/virsh domcapabilities --virttype kvm failed:
error: failed to connect to the hypervisor
error: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock': Permission denied**

Step 2: got to bellow link

https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/7677

working solution is:

I had this issue too. For me, it was an issue with the groups that were added to my user but not visible yet. I solved it by rebooting so the new group (libvirt) was actually visible for my user. You can achieve the same without rebooting by running exec sudo su -l $USER.